# Retrieve user input using a button

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

I'm trying to write my first program in JS, however I'm stuck at getting the user input from the form and displaying it after the user press a button (mot1 and mot2).
I might think it's coming from the input area, but I'm totally new to JS and I tried different script to store the input without having any result.

I tried to use :

```
var mot1 = ('input1').val();
```

or

```
document.getdocumentById('output1').value;
```

None of them has returned the value written in mot1, I'm not even sure how I should approach the problem, for me, I say that the value mot1 should be read and store, then display within the "alert".

```js
// bouton clickable
const button = document.querySelector("btn-lg");


//Récupère le mot n*2
var mot2 = ('Deuxième truc');
var index = i1;
// stock le résultat

function getmot() {
  //Récupère le mot n*1
  var mot1 = ('Premier truc').val();


}




function checker() {
  // Indique à l'utilisateur si les champs sont vides
  if (checkForMissingInput(false)) {
    alert('Fais un effort mon pote')
  } else {
    writeResult("output1")
  }

}


button onclick = function WriteResult() {
  // écrit le résultat
  alert(mot1);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1" />
  <title>Generateur</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="style" type="text/css" href="applistyle.css">
  <script src="scriptmot.js" />
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h2> Générateur de mots stylés </h2>
      <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="20" id="i0" placeholder="Premier truc" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="20" id="i1" placeholder="Deuxième truc" />
      </form>

      <br />
      <br />

      <button type="button" class="btn-lg" id="submit" onClick=>Bang!</button>

      <br />
      <br />

      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">Résultat :</span>

        </div>
        <textarea id="output1" rows="1" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a bunch of syntax errors in that code. Also, `const button = document.querySelector("btn-lg");` won't work because a) `btn-lg` is a class, so you need `".btn-lg"` and b) the script runs before the button exists. Move it down to the end of `<body>`, after your other scripts.

Comment: Thanks you ! So I edited the lin to the button with a dot instead, and moved the script in the bottom of the HTML, the button still seem to do nothing tho

Comment: Is this JavaScript at all?

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ayrkg3pc/ Best study it extensively :)

Comment: you need to put jquery on top of the code (and before bootstrap)..

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, gonna deconstruct the example Chris provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add on your scriptmot.js like below:

```
function checker(){

    document.getElementById("output1").value = document.getElementById("i0").value + document.getElementById("i1").value;
    alert();
}
```

then add function for your onclick like below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-lg" id="submit" onClick=checker();>Bang!</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, so the function can be added directly on the html file ?

Comment: Yes, you can add directly in html. You need add <script>  code her </script>